# Python-declare specific region for image clicking

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am new for Python!
I would like to define a small region for reading the image, not searching the whole screen. I have some code below but not successful:

```html
import pyautogui, time
while True:    
    if pyautogui.screenshot(region=(666,0, 200, 200)pyautogui.locateOnScreen(r'C:\Users\Lawrence\Desktop\PyTest\image.png', grayscale=True)):
       pyautogui.click(1880,15)
       time.sleep(0.1)
       break
```

Hopefully somebody can help! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
import pyautogui, time

while True:
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen(image=r'C:\Users\Lawrence\Desktop\PyTest\image.png', region=(666,0, 200, 200), grayscale=True):
        pyautogui.click(1880,15)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        break
```

Comment: Hi Jesper, I got error msg: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'locateOnScreen' is not defined

Comment: So sorry, I forgot `pyautogui.` before `locateOnScreen`. Couldn't test the code because of the hardcoded filename. Corrected now.

Comment: Thank you Jesper, you are really knowledgeable and helpful :)

Comment: You're so welcome, Yung Lin Ma! Glad I could help. :-)